# Slider Not Sliding More Than One Iteration Each Way (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, events, slider, counter

I have a slider that has 4 articles on it. I can get it to slide each way by 1 article, but can't seem to get it to repeat the action on the second time of clicking the 'left' button. I'm not sure if it's the counter that is the problem or the transform value? I do need to use `transform` instead of `left` or `right` because I need it execute at 60fps on the animation.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/vYXJyqZ

```js
var leftButton = document.getElementById("left-button"),
  rightButton = document.getElementById("right-button"),
  article = document.querySelectorAll(".article"),
  counter = 0,
  articleWidth = article.offsetWidth;

if (counter <=1) {
  leftButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    article.forEach(function (item) {
      item.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
      item.style.transition = "all 2s";

      counter += 1;
    });
  });
}

if (counter < article.length) {
  rightButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    article.forEach(function (item) {
      item.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
      item.style.transition = "transform 2s";

      counter -= 1;
    });
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.article-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 160%;
}

.article {
  width: 70%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="article-wrapper">
    <article class="article">
      <p>Article 1</p>
    </article>
    <article class="article">
      <p>Article 2</p>
    </article>
    <article class="article">
      <p>Article 3</p>
    </article>
    <article class="article">
      <p>Article 4</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="left-button">Left</button>
<button id="right-button">Right</button>
```

Comment: The underlying problem here is that your code logic is backwards. You are testing the value of `counter` and assigning click listener functions based on that, but that's not going to work at all; you need to assign those click listeners outside any test, then test the value of `counter` *inside* the listener function, and act accordingly.

Comment: Also note that it's easier to use `position: relative`, then simply assign a pixel value `element.style.left`, and you can just do that to the wrapper element, you don't have to move each individual article.

Comment: Here's working code: https://jsfiddle.net/28xym70t/1/

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you only need to add the event listeners once and there's no need to condition adding event listeners off of the `counter`. If you use the `counter` approach, you can return early in the click handler when the desired criteria is met.

The next issue is that your "left" handler isn't working more than once because your transform has to be 100 * counter transformed. The following code keeps pretty close to your initial design but generally works.

```js
var leftButton = document.getElementById("left-button"),
  rightButton = document.getElementById("right-button"),
  article = document.querySelectorAll(".article"),
  counter = 0,
  articleWidth = article.offsetWidth;


leftButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (counter === article.length) return;
  counter += 1;
  article.forEach(function (item) {
    item.style.transform = `translateX(-${counter}00%)`;
    item.style.transition = "all 2s";
  });
});

rightButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (counter === 0) return;
  counter -= 1;
  article.forEach(function (item) {
    item.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
    item.style.transition = "transform 2s";
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.article-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 160%;
}

.article {
  width: 70%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="article-wrapper">
    <article class="article">
      <p>Article 1</p>
    </article>
    <article class="article">
      <p>Article 2</p>
    </article>
    <article class="article">
      <p>Article 3</p>
    </article>
    <article class="article">
      <p>Article 4</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="left-button">Left</button>
<button id="right-button">Right</button>
```

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for taking the time to answer, I initially though this worked but if you click through all of the articles and then go back to the beginning, the next time you click 'left' it goes all of the way through to the final article?